# Read a variable from a running process in Python

Tags: python, variables, process

I would like to read a variable from a running process. In the example below I run a.py first, then I want to have b.py read the current value of x as it appears in the running process. As the code currently stands, it spawns a new process and gives me values of x that don't correspond to the original process that is of interest.

a.py

```
x = 0
while True:
   x = x + 1
   print(x)
```

b.py

```
from a import x
print("Current X value =", x)
```

Thank you,

Comment: Read through multiprocessing. It will provide you idea on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. Part of the reason for the question is that decoupling the real scripts from a multiprocessing environment simplifies a lot from a people / development viewpoint. Given we just need to see one single variable is there an intermediate strategy (i.e. write to disk) or something similar that can allow us to see the variable? In real terms, if we could read the variable 2 times per second the system would work.